# Is there any non linear dimensionality reduction algorithm that returns a projection matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

Is there any non linear dimensionality reduction algorithm that returns a projection matrix $W$, such as Kernel PCA and Kernel LDA does?

The projection matrix $W$ can be a non linear transformation matrix. My goal is to find a method that don't have any optimization requirements when projecting data onto a new dimension, such as Isomap, Umap etc. have.

Comment: Matrix or just transformation function that can be applied to new data?

Comment: @Dave Transformfunction would be OK.

Comment: @Dave Locality Preserving Projection (LPP) is the only dimension reduction technique I know that are linear, but it can handle nonlinear data.